# how do i recover my data

Tags: data-recovery

My data on my windows phone formatted when I connected it to my pc(ubuntu 14.04), I did not format it, it was working fine before. Can anyone give me a reason as to how that happened?

Comment: Probably a Windows error. Is it on a removable card?

Comment: What exactly did you do, when you connected your phone? I doubt that merely connecting it results in the deletion of data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question does not match up with my experience using Ubuntu in regards to phones (and I have had a few).

Ubuntu understands and recognizes foreign filesystems (ie. NTFS, FAT and many more) and will let you use them. If a storage medium has a valid filesystem on it, Ubuntu will be happy to use it OR error out if it is an unknown or a broken filesystem.

Heck, there is NO device in the world that gets formatted by a Linux system without a user at least confirming once. And even then, you also will need permissions to do such a thing. Ubuntu cannot format a micro SD card on a Windows phone that is not rooted and you either would need 3rd party software to do that or need to type in the commands to do so.

Even if the storage medium is broken and there are errors making it impossible to find a filesystem and Ubuntu would even see it as unformatted, it would not format it but throw an error when you try to access it.

If it was a formatting of the storage medium, it is more likely that your Windows system did this ([1 example](https://www.engadget.com/2010/11/17/windows-phone-7s-microsd-mess-the-full-story-and-how-nokia-ca/) of Windows phones messing with userdata).

Could it be you did not properly unmount the card from the phone before unplugging it? That would be pretty much similar to what you describe here.

> how do i recover my data?

Restore a backup? Restoring data from a Windows device is off topic but you will find good results on [Super User](https://superuser.com) (our sister site regarding Windows). For instance: [Recover data from an SD](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card) mentions [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (and [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)). I hope you get it sorted out though. On some phones, you cannot read the internal SD card with PhotoRec though and it might be impossible to get the deleted data back.